# WordPress ( Search Results Found )

Tags: wordpress, elementor

How can I hide Search Results Found?

[Please see the screenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzoAI.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) Use CSS.  See if there's an html selector around text, then add css to display: none

2) edit search template (if you have custom theme/child theme) - take text out

3) harder, but technically possible.  Add translation that basically return empty string